# Python pandas .str.split regex=True ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas, regex, split

I need help with this pandas split with regex. I'm getting the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`.

my column of data is like this

```
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30 UOFU BOOKSTORE 1 …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29 WM SUPERC Wal-Mart Sup …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29 KFC/AW #526 …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/31 UU VISITOR PARKING …
ATM WITHDRAWAL AUTHORIZED ON 04/03 Main Street …
```

my code is

```
df[['Auth_date', 'Description']] = df['Description'].str.split('(?<=\d{2}\d{2}).', regex=True)
```

desired results would be.

```
Auth_date                            Description
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30         UOFU BOOKSTORE 1 …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29         WM SUPERC Wal-Mart Sup …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29         KFC/AW #526 …
PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/31         UU VISITOR PARKING …
ATM WITHDRAWAL AUTHORIZED ON 04/03   Main Street …
```

Comment: Add `expand=True`

Comment: @BeRT2me Are you sure? I tried `...str.split('(?<=\d{2}\d{2}).', expand=True, regex=True)`. It didn't work.

Comment: Both yes and no. It looks like your Regex may be incorrect, which is a different problem.

Comment: `re.split('(?<=\d{2}\d{2}).', "PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30 UOFU BOOKSTORE")` Doesn't split your string.

Comment: @BeRT2me No it does not.

Comment: You forgot to account for the `/`

Comment: @BeRT2me So the `re.split('(?<=\d{2}/\d{2}).', "PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30 UOFU BOOKSTORE")` does work. 
For Pandas `df['Description'].str.split('(?<=\d{2}/\d{2}).', expand=True, regex=True)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
                                         Description
0    PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30 UOFU BOOKSTORE 1 …
1  PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29 WM SUPERC Wal-Mar...
2         PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29 KFC/AW #526 …
3  PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/31 UU VISITOR PARKING …
4   ATM WITHDRAWAL AUTHORIZED ON 04/03 Main Street …
```

Doing:

```
df[['Auth_date', 'Description']] = df['Description'].str.split('(?<=\d{2}/\d{2}).', expand=True, regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Description                           Auth_date
0        UOFU BOOKSTORE 1 …        PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/30
1  WM SUPERC Wal-Mart Sup …        PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29
2             KFC/AW #526 …        PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/29
3      UU VISITOR PARKING …        PURCHASE AUTHORIZED ON 03/31
4             Main Street …  ATM WITHDRAWAL AUTHORIZED ON 04/03
```

Works fine for me.